# Scanner não funcionando

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Estou tentando fazer um programinha, mas o Scanner parece não estar funcional.

Sempre que coloco para printar ele retorna 0 independente dos números, sendo que era para retornar o maior número.

Ele na classe View funciona normal, porém queria implementar o Controller.

CODE:

Controller.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Controller {
  int num1, num2;

  public void getNums (){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    num1 = scan.nextInt();
    num2 = scan.nextInt();
  }
}
```

MaiorNumero.java

```
public class MaiorNumero {
  public int maiorNumero (int num1, int num2)
  {
    if (num1 > num2){
      return num1;
    }
    else {
      return num2;
    }
  }
}
```

View.java

```
public class View extends Controller {

  public void requestNums(){
    System.out.println("1º e 2º Número"
    +"\nex. 1 2"
    +"\n:");
  }

  public void printMaior(){
    MaiorNumero mn = new MaiorNumero();
    System.out.println(mn.maiorNumero(num1, num2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de mais, não sei que modelo MVC estás a usar, mas nos meus projetos o módulo View nunca extende o controller, cada um dos módulos deve ser totalmente independente!
Na tua classe View, no método printMaior() estás a chamar o método maiorNumero e passas duas variáveis num1 e num2 que ainda não foram inicializadas (pelo menos no código que meteste aqui). Experimenta chamar o método getNums antes do maiorNumero:

```
public void printMaior(){
    MaiorNumero mn = new MaiorNumero();
    this.getNums();
    System.out.println(mn.maiorNumero(num1, num2));
  }
```

Comment: Então, estou iniciando ainda e só estou tentando fazer com que tenha um View e um Controller, mas agradeço pelo aviso.

Comment: e é verdade eu não chamei o getNums.
agora funcionou.
só uma dúvida, precisa realmente do this na parte do getNums?

Comment: o this não é necessário, ele representa o objeto ao qual foi passado o método. No entanto é boa prática escrever this pois o código fica mais claro, percebe?

Comment: hm, compreendo.

Comment: no caso do MVC estaria "certo" eu extender o Controller p/ a View ao invés da View p/ o Controller?

Comment: não, na arquitetura MVC nenhum módulo pode "conhecer" ou ter acesso direto ao outro, ao extender um deles para o outro está a violar esta regra. Para "comunicar" entre eles tem que ser o controlador a passar as informações, por exemplo, se receber um resultado do modelo, o controlador tem que passar para a View para ela dar print no ecrã.

Comment: ah, então eu realmente estava fazendo errado. agradeço!